# Handling sorting, tags, search, paging of a list

Tags: html, template-toolkit, dancer

I have a page which displays a list of elements, but I want to be able to handle sorting, paging, tags, and searching of this list.

So, for example, I want the tag links/search box/page links to include all of the other parameters. How can I do this using template toolkit?

As an example, on the page

`/example`

the tag `foo` will link to `/example?tag=foo`. However, if the page represents a sorted search, the page may be

`/example?search=bar&sort=name`

so I want the tag link to include these parameters, so `/example?search=bar&sort=name&tag=foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of additional parameters that automatically get passed to template toolkit.  Here is the documentation:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Template::Abstract

You will notice that one of them is params.  So, within TT, you could build something like this:

```
    <a href="/example?search=<% params.search %>&sort=<% params.sort %>&tag=<% params.tag %>"> ... </a>
```

Of course, if you wanted to get fancier, you could add them only conditionally.  For example:

```
     ... <% IF params.sort %>&sort=<% params.sort %><%END%> ...
```